# cakephp 2.6.1 ajax login not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Having issues logging in with ajax. Can anyone direct me to some documentation that makes sense. This sounds worrying.

> In 2.x $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in
>   with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3
>   $this->Auth->login($this->data) would try to identify the user first
>   and only log in when successful.

```
$data['User']['email'] = "this";
$data['User']['password'] = "that";
```

---

```
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);

$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('json');

if ($this->Auth->login($data)){
    echo "access";
} else {
    echo "access denied";
}
```

It always prints "access".

In AppController.php

```
'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'posts',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                ),
            )
        ),
```

Comment: That's why the docs also state to use `$this->Auth->login()` (no args!) instead. Than it is not worrying.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AuthComponent::identify()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-AuthComponent.html#749-768) instead. But this can (and clearly should) be done better. Your code tells me that you don't have much experience with json in CakePHP.

Check [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) of the manual. Also your request should be made with "Accept: application/json" then your data should automatically end up in $this->request->data and [then login() should pick it up automatically](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-AuthComponent.html#607). The proper way is to send the Accept header and not just rely on the extension, this is general and not just specific to CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks I will check out identify. As for the json, im using a angularjs app, and constructing a rest api end point, hence the $this->request->input('json_decode', true); Do you have experience with that?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on two apps that both use AngularJS and Cake2 and Cake3. Do you have the RequestHandler component loaded? AFAIK it should detect the json accept header and act accordingly and get the data. But we've build a system to abstract the service layer completely.